# RadixUI + tailwind generates a wrong css selector

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, radix-ui

I am creating a website in Nextjs, with Tailwindcss and RadixUI.
Following the documentation for Radix UI's Navigation Menu, I am trying to add an animation on the content part.

I can't get the animations to work when my content section of my navigation menu shows up.

```
<NavigationMenu.Content className={[ 'data-[motion=to-start]:navigationContentReveal data-[motion=to-end]:navigationContentHide', contentSlot({}), ].join(' ')} >
```

But, when I look at the generated css, this is what the output looks like:

```
.data-[motion=to-start]:navigationContentReveal[data-motion=to-start] {
animation: navigationContentReveal 0.8 cubic-bezier(0.44, 0, 0, 0.98);
}

.data-[motion=to-end]:navigationContentHide[data-motion=to-end] {
animation: navigationContentHide 0.8 cubic-bezier(0.44, 0, 0, 0.98);
}
```

Now, I think this is not correct, right?

versions:
"@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.4",
"tailwindcss-radix": "^2.8.0",

Tried it with creating keyframs and animations in my tailwind config, now moved them to CSS, but all to no avail.

Anyone any idea?